# jsp malicious file upload is possible, but no exploit scenario, should I report it?

Tags: penetration-test, file-upload

I was pen testing a java web application, I could upload a malicious JSP file which was generated using METASPLOIT, however, I could not put the JSP file in the server directory so that it can be executed and a web shell session opened.

However, I do not know if the attacker could somehow exploit such file.

Should I report it as a vulnerability and ask the developers to scan the file before uploading or I just ignore it?

Comment: What kind of file application was expecting ?

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you can upload a JSP file is in itself not a vulnerability.

Particularly, if the file contents are put in a database there is no actual JSP file on disk. Therefore, it can't be placed in the webroot and it won't be executed.

If the file *is* written to disk and you can put it in an arbitrary location, there is a risk. If you failed to exploit this because you don't know the path of the webroot, for example, someone with more time and knowledge may succeed in exploiting it.

I wouldn't advise scanning uploaded files for JSP content. If there is no way to put the uploaded file in the webroot there is no risk.

Comment: what if i could upload a pdf file that contains javascript code (created by metasploit) and could not be executed from my side at the moment ?

Comment: @Tom - That's a client-side attack and does not pose a risk to the server.

Answer (score 0):

At best, the risk itself is an **Unrestricted File Upload** function. - However, the file in its present state couldn't be executed. This suggests that the uploads are stored in a folder that does not have execute permission.

However in the present configuration, it's a reduced risk. It's worth noting the risk of the unrestricted file-upload as a **low** or **medium** risk finding since the code is not rendered. Use the CVSS calculator to determine. If there's ever an administrator error re-configuring the file-system, then they should be cognizant of possible critical risk for code execution and seek to move towards using best practice. OWASP recommends using server-side enforced file upload controls (always push for WHITELISTING!) to prevent them from the open-door possibility of human error.